# preg_replace is not removing the invisible character in CSV data

Tags: php, string, csv, preg-replace, preg-match

I've a data (below). Regex **`[^\x00-\x7F]+`** is finding it perfectly in Phpstorm and in sublime [here](https://prnt.sc/qd1qp4) but with `preg_replace` it is not working instead output is there with extra comma that is disturbing my data in CSV.

```
com,00 441458850609‬,6 Ha
```

Php regex code is [Php Code](https://prnt.sc/qd1yzx)

```
$data = preg_replace( '/[^\x00-\x7F]/', null, $data );
```

output is [Output](https://prnt.sc/qd1quq) . It is adding this extra comma and because of it my data is going wrong. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Try writing your code in double quotes, as now it's literal `\x` and not escape char

Comment: did that ```"/[^\x00-\x7F]/+"``` & ```"[^\x00-\x7F]"``` . Nothing worked.

Comment: Invisible characters can be really many. Try `preg_replace("/(?![\r\n\t])\p{C}/u", "", $data)`. Or `"/(?![\r\n\t])\p{Cc}/u"`

Comment: Look like your provided string already escaped by stackoverflow, could you please give us the link of part of the file so we can test it?

Comment: Also, try `preg_replace('~[^[:ascii:]]~u', '', $data)`

Comment: Alex, no provided string has that character ( https://prnt.sc/qd676h ). Wiktor sure i'll check and comment here.